# PHP + MongoDB - Fetch entry from array inside collection with $elemMatch not working

Tags: php, mongodb, mongodb-query

I have the following object:

```
{
    users: {
        _id: "users",
        entries: 
        [
            {
                _id: 1,
                username: "taxicala",
                password: "password"
            },
            {
                _id: 2,
                username: "guest",
                password: "guest"
            }
        ]
    }
}
```

And I want to select only one user that is within the "entries" array. I am trying the following:

```
$entry = $this->_users->find(
             array('entries' => 
                 array('$elemMatch' => 
                     array('username' => 'taxicala')
                 )
             )
         );
```

The result I get is an empty object:

```
{ }
```

I could not find any clue over Google or here about this. Am I doing something wrong? Am I missing something? or is '$elemMatch' not supported by PHP?

Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

$elemMatch is supported but as far as you document goes, you `entries` are inside the user `object`. So at least in your query you have to put `array('users.entries' => ...)`. Also I do not see why do you need to use $elemMatch.

`db.coll.find({"users.entries.username" : "taxacala"})` outputs the documents with username "taxacala".

Comment: Thanks! That worked for me, nevertheless, I figured out I was formatting my data in an incorrect way, I was adding a users object to the users collection. This is what you get when you are new to something :D. But the answer you gave me was correct.